# Leer un CSV en R, desde otro generado por R

Tags: r, csv, data

Explico mi situación actual, quiero poder guardar un fichero CSV en un sistema operativo y cargarlo en el otro sin tener que indicar el tipo de columna. Explico el porqué. Cuando tu tienes en R un *data.frame* del estilo:

```
data.frame(V1=c("1","2","3"),V2=c(1,2,3), stringAsFactor=TRUE)
```

Cuando tu escribes un CSV con este data.frame quedaría así:

```
"V1","V2"
"1", 1
"2", 2
"3", 3
```

En cambio cuando se realiza la lectura de ese CSV la columna **V1** es igual a la **V2**. ¿Existe alguna función que detecte las comillas y lo codifique como *factor*?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, la misma función te puede servir, con la salvedad que le debes indicar el tipo de dato. Veamos:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("1","2","3"),
                 V2=c(1,2,3),
                 stringsAsFactors = T,
                 row.names=NULL
                 )
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ V2: num  1 2 3
```

Ahora, deberíamos leer el archivo salvado, pero indicando la naturaleza de cada columna mediante el parámetro `colClasses`:

```
df <- read.csv("Ejemplo.csv", 
               colClasses=c("factor", "numeric"))

str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ V2: num  1 2 3
```

Otra forma más automática y que tal vez se acerque más a lo que buscas, sería, ignorar las `"`, dejar que las cadenas pasen tal cual están en el archivo, es decir encomilladas, esto nos asegura que los números seguirán siendo considerados cadenas, el problema que tiene esto, es que los `levels` del factor tendrán comillas, por lo que lo único que restaría es quitar las mismas, algo así:

```
df <- read.csv("Ejemplo.csv", 
               quote = "",
               stringsAsFactors = T)

for (f in names(df)[sapply(df, is.factor)]) {
    levels(df[,f]) <- gsub("\"", "", levels(df[,f]))
}
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X.V1.: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ X.V2.: int  1 2 3
```